# cmake option default value if else

Tags: cmake-gui

I tried to do that, but it doesn't appear on the cmake gui, how have I got to do to change the default value of option depending of S.O, and it appear in the cmake gui?

```
if(UNIX)
  option(HASH "enable hash" ON)
else()
  option(HASH "enable hash" OFF)
endif()
```

Comment: Just wondering, was the option given to `mark_as_advanced`? That would certainly inhibit it from being displayed on the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you `unset` or `mark_as_advanced` the `HASH` variable, it should appear in the CMake GUI.